# Getting an error when displaying my react app in the browser

Tags: reactjs

Below is the error that it returns in the browser. Kindly help

./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prefix_exceptions' of undefined
at Array.map ()

Comment: add more details to this question. When this error happened ?

Comment: Try npm install --save-dev webpack

Comment: ok thanks let me try this

Comment: was opening a new react app as usual for a project. After all the dependencies were were availed, it was time to npm start then it gave me a notification that its opening the dev server only for the error to pop up in the localhost3000.

Comment: Tried the above installation but the error still persists.